# How to deal with multilingual interfaces?

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, globalization

I'm facing a problem mainly with how much space multilingual text in controls take up.

Here's an example.

English:

[image]

German:

[image]

As you can see the text in the German version is following on in the control leaving me with an un-usable interface.

note, these are entered into label controls.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Don't use static dimensions/values for your layout.

Comment: as in the dark gray background panel needs to be set to auto?

Comment: Something other than a static value, yes. Basically, don't say `Width="500"`, say `Width="2*"` or `Width="50%"` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this as an answer since I'm pretty sure this is your problem:

Don't use static layout dimensions, i.e:

**Bad**

```
Width="500"
```

**Good**

```
Width="2*"
Width="50%"
Width="Auto"
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see Auto working, "2*" or a percentage however aren't, I'm taking a guess 2* means size 2 or above right?

Comment: @SandeepBansal no, 2* means space the element proportionally in the available space; twice the size of a * element, half the size of a 4* element, etc.

Comment: If at some point you have to specify a maximum width, standard practice is to make it 130% of the English text width. This statistically works, but some individual texts may still be too long - sometimes you can find a solution then by working closely with the translators, but you need to allow them some space.  
Also note that if you ever localize to Asian languages, height might become a problem for one-line elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to expect long string. Testing earlier (i.e. during development) is important.

[Pseudo-localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_localization) is useful technique to deal with it early in the process. I.e. your text for "pseudo-loc" culture would be "[!!! εNetwork usageğ§ !!!]" and you'd see this layout problem sooner.

Flexible layout and generally giving more space for strings are often necessary to accommodate international strings.